# How to get pixel shader version and vertex shader version in c++

Tags: c++, directx, version, shader, pixel

as memtioned in title, I need to get pixel shader version and vertex shader version in c++ code.But I don't know how to do it. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: I tried to use glGetString, but failed to get a correct result.

Comment: Get the version from what? From the driver/hardware, from a compiled shader blob, what?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Enter chrome://gpu in the browser address bar, and you will see pixel shader version in the page. That's what i want

Comment: What version of DirectX are you using? 9, 10, 11, 12?

Comment: The "pixel shader version" was a capability in Direct3D 9. In Direct3D 10 or later, it's implied by the [Direct3D hardware feature level](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/).

Answer (score 1):

What you create device you are passing an array of [`D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476329(v=vs.85).aspx) values, when function succeeds the chosen feature level will be returned as through `pFeatureLevel` pointer. Returned feature level determines highest shader version supported by video adapter.

```
constexpr const ::std::array<::D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL, 4> feature_levels
{
    ::D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0
,   ::D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0
,   ::D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1
,   ::D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10
};
::ID3D11Device * naked_p_device{};
::D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL selected_feature_level{};
::ID3D11DeviceContext * naked_p_device_context{};
if
(
    SUCCEEDED
    (
        ::D3D11CreateDevice
        (
            p_adapter
        ,   D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN
        ,   nullptr
        ,   creation_flags
        ,   feature_levels.data()
        ,   static_cast< ::UINT >(feature_levels.size())
        ,   D3D11_SDK_VERSION
        ,   ::std::addressof(naked_p_device)
        ,   ::std::addressof(selected_feature_level)
        ,   ::std::addressof(naked_p_device_context)
        )
    )
)
{
    // inspect selected_feature_level...
}
```

[Table of feature level capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876(v=vs.85).aspx#Overview)

Comment: but it remains a question how we can get current pixel shader version

Comment: @Frank Shader version directly corresponds to feature level.